# Round Values pushed from a JSON with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rounding

I'm absoluteley new to JS and i cant figuere out how i should proceed to round the values (Counter1 & Counter2) which come from the external File IOCounter.html with a Json-Structure.

I tried to put the math.round() to different places within the code which seemed to be logical for me- but nothing worked.

Do i have to define Var's, round these and write the the result to the label?

Thanks for your help.

```
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <label id="counter1">0</label>
  <label id="counter2">0</label>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON("IOCounter.htm", function(result) {
                $('#counter1').text(result["counter1"]);
                $('#counter2').text(result["counter2"]);

            });
        },50);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `IOCounter.htm` contains JSON and not HTML? Then rename it to `IOCounter.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using the code within a webserver of a PLC.Not quite sure if i'm allowed to use the json-extension. Anyway... Now it works. tried it locally with htm and json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define vars per se. you could to this:

```
$('#counter1').text(Math.round(result["counter1"]));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly.
I thout i have tried exactly this before... maybe i made a further mistake.
Thanks again. Nice weekend!

Comment: Hi again.

I used:

    $('#counter1').text(Math.round(result["counter1"]*100)/100);

to get two digits behind the comma.
But if there are no Numbers behind the comma- this method does not print the XY.00 - but only XY

So i tried this:

    $('#counter1').text(result["counter1"].toFixed(2));

Now it is exactly what i was looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out :) nice weekend to you too